# SQL how to "join" two tables

Tags: sql, join

can't imagine simple solution. I've two tables. 
table 1 (about 300 rows)

| id | name | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | peter | 12:00:00 |
| ID2 | alice | 12:33:00 |
| ID3 | tom | 08:00:00 |

table 2 (about 3'000'000 rows)

| id | time | arg1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | 12:00:00 | 23 |
| ID1 | 11:00:00 | 34 |
| ID2 | 12:45:00 | 21 |
| ID2 | 12:33:00 | 22 |
| ID2 | 08:00:00 | 12 |
| ID3 | 08:00:00 | 21 |
| ID1 | 08:00:00 | 23 |

need output table like this

| id | name | time | arg1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | peter | 12:00:00 | 23 |
| ID2 | alice | 12:33:00 | 22 |
| ID3 | tom | 08:00:00 | 21 |

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Which row in `table2` should be used for each row in `table1`? e.g. for ID1 (Peter), why should `time = 12:00, arg1 = 23` be used instead of `11:00, arg1 = 34` ?

Comment: Have you tried `JOIN`?

Comment: table 1 says: peter did something in 12:00 <br /> table 2 says user IDx do 34 in 11:00 <br /> and output i need "what peter did in 12:00"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select t1.ID, t1.time, t1.name, t2.arg1 from table1 t1
Inner join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
Where t1.time=t2.time
```

Comment: works, it works ! THANK YOU ALL. (in my many attempts i tried also this monstrosity "select P.id, name,time arg1 from ( select id, max(time) as time from t2 group by id) P inner join t2 on P.id = t2,id and P.time = t2.time left outer join t1 on p.id=t1.id order by name)